# How to make an oblique oval in CSS?

Tags: html, css, web, geometry

I am trying to create an oblique oval in CSS/HTML, but having some issues.

I have tried creating a normal oval and then rotating it a few degrees according to the code below, but it just rotates the underlying rectangle and applies the bordier radius thereafter.

Here is what I tried:

```
.circle{
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    border-radius:50px;
    background:#000;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(27deg);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shall use a relative `border-radius`, and set it to 50% to have a perfect oval.

Then, you could try with `skew` instead :

```
.circle{
    -webkit-transform: skew(27deg);
}
```

Will render this : [image: skew]

While `rotate` will render this: [image: rotate]

Comment: @gustavlrssn What did you choose?

Answer (score 0):

Try making your border radius 50% (or 500px)

```
border-radius:50%;
```

Edit: to improve my answer, the code you posted is correct for creating an oblique oval, except that the border radius is not correct. It needs to be 50%, as that makes perfect corners, eg. for a circle. Then you just use the width/height to stretch the circle to get an oval, and use the `transform:rotate(27deg);` to make it an oblique oval.

Answer (score 0):

Working here, I just put `border-radius: 50%;`

http://jsfiddle.net/4RkhW/